# Converting QEMU command line args to libvirt domain xml

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I have a hard time converting this QEMU command to a libvirt domain XML:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm \
-m 3072 \
-cpu core2duo \
-machine q35 \
-smp 2 \
-usbdevice keyboard \
-usbdevice mouse \
-vga std \
-device isa-applesmc,osk="${osx_osk_key}" \
-kernel "${chameleon_file_path}" \
-device ide-drive,bus=ide.2,drive=MacHDD \
-drive id=MacHDD,if=none,cache=none,file="${vm_hdd_img_file_path}"
-netdev user,id=hub0port0 \
-device virtio-net,netdev=hub0port0,id=eth0
```

It works perfectly if I call it from a Terminal (Ubuntu 14.10) but the `virsh domxml-from-native qemu-argv` fails for the MacHDD -device with this error:

```
error: internal error: missing index/unit/bus parameter in drive 'id=MacHDD,if=none,cache=none,file="${vm_hdd_img_file_path}"'
```

*(Note: of course I tried it with actual paths in place of the variables, same error - and if I remove the last two args it converts it to domain XML even with the variables included)*

How could I solve this? Or what would be the equivalent of the last two args in domain xml? (Tried a lot of different combinations but couldn't get it work with libvirt/virsh)

**EDIT**

For the record this is what I get running virsh's domain-from-native command without the -device -drive

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>unnamed</name>
  <uuid>38cafecb-4774-4590-83eb-e576a79aab93</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>3145728</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>3145728</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='q35'>hvm</type>
    <kernel>${chameleon_file_path}</kernel>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>core2duo</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='dmi-to-pci-bridge'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pci-bridge'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='sdl'/>
    <video>
      <model type='vga' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='none'/>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='isa-applesmc,osk=&quot;${osx_osk_key}&quot;'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-netdev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='user,id=hub0port0'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='virtio-net,netdev=hub0port0,id=eth0'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

But I can't figure out what would be the equivalent of the -device -drive in this situation and I'm unable to create a VM from this domain xml.

Even without the MacHDD -device and -drive I get this error when I try to create the VM with `$ virsh create`

```
error: Failed to create domain from libvirt.xml
error: internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-38cafecb-4774-4590-83eb-e576a79aab93'
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

Change:

```
-drive id=MacHDD,if=none,cache=none,file="${vm_hdd_img_file_path}"
```

For

```
-drive id=MacHDD,if=ide,index=2,file="${vm_hdd_img_file_path}"
```

Answer (score 1):

TBH I'm not that familiar with libvirt, but wouldn't it be something like:

```
   <disk type='file' device='disk'>
     <source file='/path/to/image.img'/>
     <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
   </disk>
```

Comment: I think I tried something like this but I'll git it a try.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
  <source file='/home/vbox/mac_hdd_10.10Chimera410R1280x1024x32TV.img'/>
  <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
  <boot order='1'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
<seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor' relabel='yes'/>
```

This is what [kimchi](http://kimchi-project.github.io/kimchi/) has done, when I created VM using virt-manager. And thanks for that `<qemu:commandline>` thing. I was looking for it. If possible could you please point out any info on sound working with Mac OS X KVM?